# Qualcomm MSM8974 JPEG encoder hardware kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, jpeg, qualcomm

I'm trying to use hardware JPEG decoder on Samsung S5 for my android application. The reason behind this is that Androids BitmapFactory, or NDK libjpeg-turbo is not fast enough to process images at desired frame rate.

It is hard to confirm that this platform has hardware decoder, due to lack of datasheet. Only trail I found is that char devices (`/dev/jpeg0`, `/dev/jpeg1`, `/dev/jpeg2`) exists in the system.

I've traced that to kernel driver (this is Lineage14.1 codebase) `kernel/samsung/klte/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/jpeg_10/`. After recompiling it with debug enabled I get (`dmesg | grep jpeg`):

```
[    0.413878] msm_iommu_v1 fda64000.qcom,iommu: device jpeg_iommu mapped at c4fe0000, with 3 ctx banks
[    0.419962] msm_iommu_ctx_v1 fda6c000.qcom,iommu-ctx: context jpeg_enc0 using bank 0
[    0.420093] msm_iommu_ctx_v1 fda6d000.qcom,iommu-ctx: context jpeg_enc1 using bank 1
[    0.420218] msm_iommu_ctx_v1 fda6e000.qcom,iommu-ctx: context jpeg_dec using bank 2
[    1.550260] __msm_jpeg_init:908] Jpeg Device id 0
[    1.550317] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] evt_q
[    1.550370] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_rtn_q
[    1.550374] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_buf_q
[    1.550377] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_rtn_q
[    1.550382] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_buf_q
[    1.550395] __msm_jpeg_init:925] name jpeg_enc0
[    1.550399] __msm_jpeg_init:927] ctx 0xea6dd608
[    1.550434] __msm_jpeg_init:937] dom_num 0x7
[    1.550439] __msm_jpeg_init:944] dom 0xe9ae75c0
[    1.550443] msm_jpeg_init_dev: msm_jpeg_device_p 0xe9afec00
[    1.550487] msm_jpeg_init_dev jpeg0: success
[    1.550502] __msm_jpeg_init:908] Jpeg Device id 1
[    1.550557] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] evt_q
[    1.550611] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_rtn_q
[    1.550614] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_buf_q
[    1.550617] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_rtn_q
[    1.550621] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_buf_q
[    1.550633] __msm_jpeg_init:925] name jpeg_enc1
[    1.550636] __msm_jpeg_init:927] ctx 0xea6dd808
[    1.550664] __msm_jpeg_init:937] dom_num 0x8
[    1.550668] __msm_jpeg_init:944] dom 0xe9ae7f40
[    1.550672] msm_jpeg_init_dev: msm_jpeg_device_p 0xe9aff000
[    1.550720] msm_jpeg_init_dev jpeg1: success
[    1.550735] __msm_jpeg_init:908] Jpeg Device id 2
[    1.550835] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] evt_q
[    1.550890] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_rtn_q
[    1.550893] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] output_buf_q
[    1.550897] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_rtn_q
[    1.550900] msm_jpeg_q_init:32] input_buf_q
[    1.550912] __msm_jpeg_init:925] name jpeg_dec
[    1.550916] __msm_jpeg_init:927] ctx 0xea6dda08
[    1.550947] __msm_jpeg_init:937] dom_num 0x9
[    1.550952] __msm_jpeg_init:944] dom 0xe9b0a8c0
[    1.550955] msm_jpeg_init_dev: msm_jpeg_device_p 0xe9aff400
[    1.550997] msm_jpeg_init_dev jpeg2: success
```

So it looks promising for me. But...

There is no documentation how to use it. Commit message claims that there somewhere should be userspace driver.

```
msm: camera: JPEG Encoder driver

Add support for the new JPEG 1.0 encoder hardware.This
is the kernel driver and takes input from the corresponding
userspace driver.The new encoder hardware supports
formats H2V2, H2V1, H1V2 and H1V1. It also has support for
upscaling and downscaling.
```

But I've grepped whole Android project looking for anything related to JPEG and I couldn't find it. Same as with googling.

So, I would appreciate answer with information how to use this driver for JPEG hardware decode.

Comment: Ask vendor for details?

Comment: Maybe it's one of the software jpeg decoders ported for use with the Hexagon DSP?

Comment: Maybe it's one of the software jpeg decoders ported for use with the Hexagon DSP?

Comment: @BrianCain can you elaborate a little on that? Is JPEG decoding possible on Hexagon DSP? I found [this](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/hexagon-dsp-sdk/imaging/30052) forum topic with a similar question, but unfortunately without answers.